# How to refresh payment methods section after save billing in magento/

Tags: magento, methods, refresh, payment, billing

I want to refresh payment section after edit and save billing in onepage checkout page in magento.

Comment: Is this a programming-related question?

Comment: You need to provide more information, what onepage checkout extension do you use? There is several.  Also, how do you want it refreshed, with javascript onblur or something?